# Rewrite Role does not apply

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, permalinks, pretty-urls

I have php website and I have created .htaccess file. I have two rules. One for force www and other for permalink.

I want to change following Url

```
http://www.yatha.tv/play.php?vid=1437&id=1
```

to

```
http://www.yatha.tv/1437/1.html
```

But this rule does not change

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /play.php?vid=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yatha\.tv$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yatha.tv/$1 [R=301,L]
   RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /play.php?vid=$1&id=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The rule above it - `^(.*)$` - will always match first.

Comment: @Marty No, that will match only if the `RewriteCond` was true.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Oh yes, right you are.